# How would one go about sorting in descending order when using pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
df3 = (license_data["prior_state"].count())
print(df3.sort_values(by=['prior_state'], axis=0, ascending=False, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', 
na_position='last',ignore_index=False, key=None).head(10))
```

I have tried a few different ways and I can't seem to find anything that works. I just keep getting an error message similar to this:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute `sort_values`.
```

Comment: Your data is not a dataframe or a series. Its an int.. thiss is the result of the function count()

Comment: Do you test `print (df3)` ? It is scalar, so `sort_values` has no sense and raise error, because need `DataFrame`, not scalar

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please provide a full minimal reproducible example of your problem? Please, see stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. In particular, can you provide us with the `DataFrame` or `Series` `license_data`?

Comment: The error shows you are using numpy. While sort_value is for pandas.  Did you use and import pandas correctly?  Maybe this can help you:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html    also your dataframe has problem. it is just an "Int" , not a dataframe!